# Integral $\int \sqrt{4+4x^2+1/x^2} dx$

Tags: integration

I'm totally lost on how I would integrate the following function:

$f(x) = \sqrt{4+4x^2+1/x^2}$

If anyone could even just point me to the method of integration that would be grand.

Comment: If I have understood it correctly (see my edit), you could notice that it is a perfect square.

Comment: You are probably solving an arclength problem. Typically, when you have a function $y$, differentiate, square the derivative, add $1$, take the square root, you get an awful mess that can't be integrated in elementary terms. But with **very** careful choice of constants, one can produce artificial situations where things magically simplify.

Comment: Note that it is non-trivial to compute general integrals of this form when the function under the radical is not a quadratic perfect square of linear factors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$4 + 4x^2 + \dfrac1{x^2} = \left(2x + \dfrac1x \right)^2$$
Hence,
\begin{align}
\sqrt{4 + 4x^2 + \dfrac1{x^2}} & = \begin{cases} 2x + \dfrac1x & x > 0\\ -\left( 2x + \dfrac1x\right) & x < 0\end{cases}\\
& = 2 \vert x \vert + \dfrac1{\vert x \vert}
\end{align}

Comment: Now I feel stupid, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Compute the square root!${}{}{}{}{}$